# When can you call UIEdgeInsets safeAreaInsets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to adjust my views for iPhone X but I can’t figure out when the safeAreaInsets are initialized. According to the documentation,

> If the view is not currently installed in a view hierarchy, or is not
>   yet visible onscreen, the edge insets in this property are 0.

I would think that when viewDidLoad is called, that the values would be set, but that is not the case. I can get values when viewDidLayoutSubviews is called, but that seems to be too late and doesn’t return the correct values anyway.

Can anyone explain how to use the safeAreaInsets property to me?

Comment: When `viewDidLoad` is called the view is not yet installed in a view hierarchy. If the insets are anything like the top/bottom layout guides, they're probably set during layout, which means `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should be the correct time (for the view controller's immediate view; any subviews won't have been laid out yet when `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called).

Comment: You can know when it is set (and changed, for example when rotating the device) by implementing `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange`

Answer (score 3):

They are initialized before view is layouted (hence within view hierarchy). **Best place** to access them and act accordingly is within **viewWillLayoutSubviews** method. As you have already mentioned **viewDidLayoutSubviews** is little **too late**, but willLayoutSubviews works just fine. Happy coding!